# pycaretをインストールして、PyCharmで試しています。 大量にエラーがでて上手く使用できません。

Tags: python

Anaconda環境で新規仮想環境を作り、pycaretをインストールして、PyCharmで試しています。
大量にエラーがでて上手く使用できません。もうまる１日やっております。

以下のサイトを参考に試してみようと思ったのですが、最初でつまずいています。

[PyCaretによる自動機械学習（AutoML）](https://www.logopt.com/2020/12/30/pycaret/)

下記コードを実行してみると大量にエラーがでて上手く使用できません。
以下のようなエラーいくつもでてきます。

このような状況ですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか？
アドバイスをください。よろしくお願いします。

**実行したコード:**

```
from pycaret.classification import *

mashroom = pd.read_csv("http://logopt.com/data/mashroom.csv")
mashroom.head() 
clf = setup(data = mashroom, target = 'target', session_id=123)

best_model = compare_models()
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
  FitFailedWarning)
C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:552: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to 0.000000. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\pycaret\internal\pipeline.py", line 118, in fit
    result = super().fit(X, y=y, **fit_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\imblearn\pipeline.py", line 281, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, yt, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py", line 1007, in fit
    return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py", line 109, in fit
    y_numeric=is_regressor(self))
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 432, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\env_simple\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 810, in check_X_y
    y = y.astype(np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'edible'
```

Comment: 直接の回答ではなくて申し訳ありませんが、手元のWindows10環境では問題なく実行できました。関連パッケージのバージョンは`pycaret  2.3.1`, `scikit-learn 0.23.2`, `tensorflow  2.3.1`, `pip  20.2.4`です。なお最初のpycaretインストール時にエラーが発生したので指示に従って`pip install pycaret --use-feature=2020-resolver`でオプションを付け直してインストールし直しました。左記のオプションでインストールして、それでもダメな場合は`pip install --upgrade pip` してからコードを実行すると結果は変わるでしょうか。

Comment: あとは、参照記事で更に紹介されているビデオのチャンネル[MIKIO KUBO](https://www.youtube.com/user/kubomikio/featured)で使われている環境に合わせてみるのが良いのでは？ たぶんこの辺のもの。[Jupyter Lab (Notebook) の使用法](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6kuPBWzfxg), [データサイエンス練習問題集](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz8sHu_CzBwPt3BPmwYjseKbQoIsqAO4T)

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。

pycaret 2.3.1、scikit-learn 0.23.2, pip 21.1.2 ,tensorflow なし という環境にて行っていた状況です。
なのでtensorflowをインストールしてみました。が、残念ながら問題は解決されませんでした。相変わらず同じようなメッセージが大量にでてきます。

pycaretインストール時のエラーは何度か問題が起きて、ネット検索して対処策を見つけて、今はPycaretは問題なくインストールされるようになっております。。、


できればPyCharmで使用できるようにしておきたいです。
負荷が高い状況を考えてGoogle Colaboratoryでも使用できるようにした方がいいとも思っていますが、とりあえず最初の一歩は使い慣れているPyCharm環境で利用できるようにしておきたいと思っております。

また何かお気付きのことなどありましたらアドバイスいただけたらと思います。
ありがとうございました。